# Choose different sources manually of a query using vba

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

RUN TIME ERROR:

[image]

DEBUG OPTION:

[image]

QUERY ERROR AFTER RUNNING VBA:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to choose the different Sources of a query manually via VBA. I am getting an error because it doesn't find the source.

```
Sub Import()
'
' Import Macro
'
    Dim fname As String
    fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")


    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Data", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(""" & fname & """),[Delimiter="" "", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.Rem" & _
        "oveColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""Column2""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Removed Columns"",{{""Column1"", ""HANDLE""}, {""Column3"", ""CIRCUIT""}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Top Rows"" = Table.Skip(#""Renamed Columns"",2)" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Top Rows"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Data"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Data]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Data"
        .REFRESH BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, your M code is syntactically invalid. (It shows in this particular image you posted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI6ca.png.)

To fix it, get rid of the first `)` in the `Csv.Document` call. In other words:

```
Source = Csv.Document("someFilePath",[Delimiter=" ", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
```

instead of:

```
Source = Csv.Document("someFilePath"),[Delimiter=" ", Columns=3, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
```

That should at least solve the syntax error.

---

Instead of your current approach, it might be better to instead:

1. Change your query to look up the file path from some named range (can be done with `Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` in Power Query and then drilling down).
2. When your VBA subroutine runs, write the file path (that the user provides via `Application.GetOpenFilename`) to that named range.
3. Refresh the query programmatically (as part of your VBA subroutine).
4. Everything else should work the same (as the file path is still dynamic).

The advantage here is you don't have to manipulate your M code directly in VBA, so there isn't the same risk of introducing syntax errors.

Another issue is that you are injecting direct user input into your code. In some programming contexts, this can be a vulnerability. Maybe this is not a problem for you, but it's something to consider.